# Passing data with Ajax, results backslashes in SQL statement

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I couldn't find any similar problems.

I have a form and the values from the input fields come from a SQL database.
When you edit those fields and save the changes, an ajax call is made.

In this example, I only use 1 field to be updated 'email':

```
function EditArtist(artist_id) {
    var email = $("input#email").val()
    var dataSQL = 'email="'+ email +'"';
    $.post("edit.php", { action: "EditArtist", id: artiest_id, data: dataSQL },
    function(response) {
        if(response == 1) {
            return false;
    } else {
            alert(response);
    }
    });
}
```

In `edit.php` I do following:

```
if($action == 'EditArtist') {
    $id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
    $data = $_REQUEST['data'];
    $sql = "UPDATE artist SET {$data} WHERE id=$id";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

But it always returns a SQL statement with backslashes in the statement. This is not accepted by MySQL.

```
UPDATE artist SET email = \"test@test.com\" WHERE id=1
```

Is this a common problem? Or am I doing something wrong?

Much appreciated!

Comment: First thing sending the sql statement as request is a bad idea !!

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty is right if you send an SQL with ajax you can easly edit the SQL and for example clear you database

Comment: so I should send all the values seperately?

     $.post("edit.php", { action: "EditArtiest", id: artiest_id, email: email, gender: gender, city: city },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dataSQL = 'email=' + email;
```

Edit:

Then try not to build the query this way. Use only the value with something like this:

```
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare('UPDATE table SET column = :column');
$preparedStatement->execute(array('column' => $email));
```

Comment: then I don't have quotes in my SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

you didn't connect to the database;
use:

```
$con = mysql_connect("host", "u", "pas");
mysql_select_db("your db");
$query = "
 UPDATE artist 
   SET
 email = '$data' (not {data}. use this if you are passing an array object and you should always use 'with the value inside'.It escapes '' and ""}

 WHERE id=$id";
 #then to execute the query 
mysql_query($query, $con);#you need to pass the connection handler
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rather send data in JSON like:

```
    var data = {
        email: $("input#email").val(),
        name: $("input#name").val()
    }
   $.post("edit.php", { action: "EditArtist", id: artiest_id, data: data },
        function(response) {
        }
   );
```

in php get data in array:

```
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
```